# How to convert a presto query output to a python data frame

Tags: dataframe, presto

I want to convert my query output to a python data frame to draw Line graph

```
import prestodb
import pandas as pd

conn=prestodb.dbapi.connect(
host='10.0.0.101',
port=8081,
user='hive',
catalog='hive',
schema='ong',
)

cur = conn.cursor()

query="SELECT dtime,tagName FROM machine where tagname is not null 
limit 1000"

cur.execute(query)

rows = cur.fetchall()

print(rows)

df = pd.DataFrame(query, columns=['x_axis','tagName'])
```

This is my sample output from query

```
[['2018-09-08 00:00:00.000', 26], ['2018-09-08 01:00:00.000', 26], 
['2018-09-08 02:00:00.000', 26], ['2018-09-08 03:00:00.000', 27], 
['2018-09-08 04:00:00.000', 27], ['2018-09-08 05:00:00.000', 27]]
```

how to convert this query output to a data frame using python

Answer (score 6):

It's very simple, I would suggest you to use `pyhive.presto` connector (see: https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive), to connect to presto, but also the one you use should work the same way.

Then you have a couple of options:

1 - Use presto connection and pandas `read_sql_query`

2 - Use presto cursor and use the output of fetchall as input data of the dataframe.

```py
# option 1
import pandas as pd
from pyhive import presto

connection = presto.connect(user='my-user', host='presto.my.host.com', port=8889)

df = pd.read_sql_query("select 100", connection)

print(
    df.head()
)
```

or

```py
# option 2
import pandas as pd
from pyhive import presto

connection = presto.connect(user='my-user', host='presto.my.host.com', port=8889)
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("select 100") 

df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())

print(
    df.head()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get data *and* column names into a dataframe, use this:

`df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(), columns=[i[0] for i in cur.description])`

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
print(df)